# Triggering Python Script using Keyboard Shortcut in Windows?

Tags: python, shortcut

Is it possible to trigger a python script using keyboard shortcut in windows? I could not find any guiding resources relating the same? can someone guide me with it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows OS create shortcut of Python script and open its properties using `Alt+Enter` or using `context menu`. In the `shortcut key` option add your custom key.

[image]